# "Нет(,) так нет" — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Что-то меня заклинило вчера: не смогла сообразить, нужна ли запятая в обороте "нет(,) так нет".

Answer (score 9):

Зависит от контекста:

- Если уж что-то есть, то есть, а если нет - так нет.
- — Может, так сделать?
  — Нет, так нет, надо по-другому.
- — У тебя есть эта книга?
  — Нет.
  — Нет так нет, поищу в другом месте.

Comment: Второй вариант не используется, потому что созвучно с "нет так нет". Используется: *нет, так не надо*.

Comment: @oleedd второй вариант вами может и не используется, впрочем как и мной, но вполне возможен. И я уверен, что в разговорной речи он хотя бы раз употреблялся.

Comment: Он стилистически неудачен, но привести стоило. А в третьем нестыковка. Он не искал у товарища, а спрашивал, чего "в другом месте"? Надо: *спрошу у кого-то другого*. А в первом надо соблюдать параллелизм: или два "так" (сомнительно, ведь нет союза "если... , так"), или два "то".

Comment: Ёлки-палки, это ещё не всё. А тире-то ничего не заменяет в данном случае, оно не нужно. Ещё есть сложная проблема, её даже трудно описать. Такой пример: *Если деньги есть, то круто, а если **их** нет, то печально.* Необходимо "их", потому что падеж не совпадает, иначе грамматическая нестыковка (*деньги есть — деньги нет*). В вашем примере это нужнее, потому что здесь известно, о чём идёт речь, а у вас нет. Это сложно, мало кто поймёт. Недавно исследовал такое.

Comment: Ещё пример: *С собакой игрался, гладил **её**.* Здесь уже явно, а там скрыто.