# Пунктуация в двух предложениях

Tags: пунктуация, тире, вводные-слова

Подскажите, пожалуйста, верны ли знаки препинания в предложениях?
*Болтать — не делать.

Нет значит нет.*

Answer (score 1):

• Здесь все правильно, тире ставится: **Болтать — не делать.**

> **2.** Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым, если оба они выражены неопределенной формой глагола (инфинитивом)... *Чай **пить** — не дрова **рубить*** (Посл.)...

Наличие частицы "не" тире не отменяет.
[Болтать — не мешки ворочать](https://gazeta-pravda.ru/issue/33-30820-28-marta-2019-goda/boltat-ne-meshki-vorochat/) (статья в "Правде")

[Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92)

• А вот во втором примере знаки расставляются в зависимости от контекста и от того, какое значение имеет слово "значит" (оно может быть вводным, выступать в роли союза или иметь смысл глагола "означать").

***― Нет, значит, нет**, ― не собиралась сдаваться я* (Ю. Андреева. Многоточие сборки).

*Стану похлопывать, значит, волнуешься. **Нет ― значит, нет*** (В. Каверин. Два капитана).

*Ну **нет ― значит, нет**, я молчу и молчать буду* (В. Распутин. Живи и помни).

***«Нет» значит «нет»*** (С. Самсонов. Аномалия Камлаева).

[значит](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82)

Comment: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=нет+значит+нет

Comment: Здесь нет разъяснения значения слова "нет". Это как устойчивое сочетание. Смысл такой: *нет так нет*. Только второй пример правильный, там не это.

Answer (score 0):

Дополнительный ответ

**1.** [Вопрос № 268592](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82)
Здравствуйте, скажите, как расставить знаки препинания в предложении: **Нет значит нет.**
Спасибо!
**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
Дополнительные знаки не нужны.

Не могу согласиться с таким безвариантным ответом, тем более что, как мы знаем, и "Грамота" бывает не всегда грамотна.
(Можно посмотреть недавний вопрос: [*"Как рукой сняло" — ударение*](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472721/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).)

**2.** *Это как устойчивое сочетание. Смысл такой: нет так нет.*
Смысл любой конструкции, даже считающейся устойчивой, надо рассматривать в контексте — от него и плясать, расставляя знаки.
"Нет так нет" тоже может оформляться по-разному: [*"Нет(,) так нет" — нужна ли запятая?*](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/16741/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F)

**3.** Еще примеры

> — Вот пристал как банный лист. Что я тебе, чтец-декламатор? Кстати, о декламаторах: стишок могу. Называется «Бад-Феслау». Собственного сочинения. Только без вопросов. **Понял — понял, нет — значит, нет...** И нальют вина... И без чувства вины поднимут круглые кружки выше за тех, кто выжил, за тех, кто вышел сухим из воды и живым из войны.
> С. Каледин. Стройбат

*Скажут, Бог ― есть, значит есть, скажут ― **нет, значит нет**, и нам уже ничего не остается, как покориться* (Л. И. Шестов. Афины и Иерусалим).

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143122/discussion-on-answer-by------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: А я смотрел контекст. Ха! А "нет так нет" есть в справочнике, тут уже чётко. В этих примерах да ("нет так нет" не подходит), а в тех — нет, нет такого, никакого параллелизма.